# Display dynamic Socket IO Data in a Terminal

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal

Imagine a little program like top in the terminal then with dynamic Web data:

```
OtherData


Stream1 Stream2 Stream3
```

I am using

```
process.stdout.clearLine()
process.stdout.write('\r' + returnData
```

tin NodeJS o update the Terminal. But now I have multiple Sockets streaming in data. Is it possible to 'subscribe' to these sockets and update the Terminal dynamically?

Comment: It must be possible. What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Somehow Socket/Stream Instances are mixed up in the callbacks. (code not displayed)